# Android images not shown react native

Tags: android, image, react-native

I put my images in drowable-*dpi folders,
The image name without capital letters, and its legal name.
The prefix is .png
In index.android.js file:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      AppRegistry,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      Image
    } from 'react-native';

    export default class proj extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>

            <Image source={{uri: 'background_home'}} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
      },

    });

AppRegistry.registerComponent('proj', () => proj);
```

When I run this code -> nothing... the image not shown on my android device.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Thanks!
[image: my folders and image.png picture]

Comment: Same code is working fine in my system. Can you add the screen shot of drawable directory with 'background_home' icon

Comment: Do you see the picture? I added it...

Comment: Image is in mipmap* directory. Copy it to drawable directory

Comment: I don't find drawable directory, where is it locate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for accessing images under mipmap directory in react-native as of now.

Create a directory called `drawable` under `res` directory (Parent directory of `mipmap-*`). Put your images in that directory. Then your code will work.

Later move all your images based on density to respective directories like `drawable-hdpi`,`drawable-xhdpi`,`drawable-xxhdpi` etc.

Comment: If you are following the above code then it should work. Try running 'react-native run-android'. App reload will not work since you have made changes in native code(like adding images in drawable). So you need to rebuild the project

Comment: after creating drawable folder must run react-native run-android ! Thanks